# How to calculate the distance from the camera to make a GameObject fill the screen?

Tags: unity

How do you calculate the distance from the camera so that a GameObject fills the screen? I.e. Without reaching out of the view and regardless of screen orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the difference of `transform.position` of Main Camera and `transform.position` of GameObject, **if you only want the distance between them**.

If you want something else, I think this video might help you 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFQhpwc6cKE

Comment: I think OP is asking not for the *current* distance between the object & camera, but the *required* distance they'll need to move the camera to in order for the whole object to fit on screen.

Comment: Sarvagna Shukla, thanks for your contribution. @DMGregory you're right, it's about finding the required distance to make a GameObject fit onto on the screen. I've edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks for your feedback.